# filter elements on array present on set

Tags: julia

I want to filter elements from an array of Int based on whether they are present another array (they are actually key values on a dictionary). What I have:

```
array1= [1 2 3 4 5]
array2= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

What I want (something on the lines of):

```
> filter!(a->a!=array1,array2)
[6 7 8 9 10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a two-dimensional `1×10 Array{Int64,2}` and for your case a `Vector` is normally more natural. Use commas (`,`) or perhaps if you actually have this kind of data structure drop the dimension with the `[:]` expression:

```
array1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array2= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10][:]
```

Now to filter, check id each element is in the set.

```
julia> filter(x -> !(x in Set(array1)), array2)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

If filtering is done many times this code can be done faster with binary search:

```
julia> sort!(array1);

julia> filter(x -> length(searchsorted(array1,x))==0, array2)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

Finally you can use `filter!` to modify the vector in-place.

Comment: Thanks! used the second option I'm filtering in many different `array2`